# How to find the closest airport in another country?

Tags: airports

We are trying to search for an airport in Australia which is closest to Hyderabad, India and we dont know which one it is. Is there a way we could find out which International airport in Australia is closest to Hyderabad, IN ?

Comment: what do you mean by closest? the shortest geographical distance or the shortest distance/time to fly to directly/with connections?

Comment: @Vince I would have assumed the shortest geographical distance would mean shortest flying time too. But to answer your question, we are looking for the shortest time to fly

Comment: to me the difference is whether planes fly between these 2 airports. E.g. you take a random small airport, Port Hedland International Airport, it is a good candidate in terms of shortest geographical distance to Hyderabad, but that is quite useless to know that since you most likely won't be able to find a direct commercial flight. Unless you have your private jet. That's why I think your question needed this precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Australia/Hyderabad) is your friend. You can use that service from city to city, or - as I did in this case - from country (Australia) to city (Hyderabad).

If you are fortunate enough to fly with your own plane and want to have the closest airport in terms of distance, check the [Great circle mapper](http://www.gcmap.com/search?Q=Australia&EL=Australia&ET=Fix%20location&EC=D&P=Australia&P=Australia)

Answer (score 2):

According to Google, the distance from Hyderabad to Perth is 4,209 miles:

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=distance+from+hyderabad+to+perth

the distance from Hyderabad to Darwin is 4,122 miles:

https://www.google.com.au/search?q=distance+from+hyderabad+to+darwin

Darwin will likely be the shortest and quickest air journey especially if flying via Singapore.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I think due to the limited flights to Darwin. The tickets are pretty expensive. I should have mentioned in the question, I was looking for the shortest and cheapest flight.